# Dúvida Busca no ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

ao buscar um termo "xpto no blabla bla"
preciso retornar todos os itens que possuem "xpto no blablabla"
e depois, por ordem de relevância
"xpto"
"blablabla"

alguém tem uma luz?

Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui evoluir um pouco usando o minimum_should_match:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "nome": {
        "query": "caixa som",
        "minimum_should_match": "95%"
      }
    }
 },
 "size": 15,
 "from": 15
}
```

mas não consigo buscar por mais de um field

minha ideia era:
dar prioridade a quem atende "caixa de som"
depois vir nos que tem mais relevância: "caixa" e "som"

Answer (score 4):

Para filtrar por mais de um campo usamos *Combining Queries* com a clausula *multi_match* que nos permite buscar o termo pesquisado em mais de um campo.

```
"fields":["nome","sobrenome"]
```

A questão de prioridade está relacionada com o termo de pesquisa em relação as ocorrências em que eles aparecem nos documentos indexados. Para retorna o resultado esperado será necessário montar uma consulta composta.

```
{  
   "size": "15",
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "multi_match":{  
                  "query":"caixa som",
                  "fields":[  
                     "nome"
                  ],
                  "type":"phrase",
                  "minimum_should_match": "95%"
               }
            },
            {  
               "multi_match":{  
                  "query":"caixa som",
                  "fields":[  
                     "nome"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Como resultado a query coloca com maior relevância (*score*) os documentos que contenham os termos "caixa som" obedecendo a sua ordem e proximidade, isso é possível por causa da clausula *phrase*, seguido dos documentos que contenham "caixa" ou "som".